# Сортировка по нескольким полям

Tags: sql, sql-server

Имеется таблица следующего вида, отсортированная по полю `Par_Id`, `Chi_id`:

```
   Par_id  Chi_id
      0       1
      0       2
      0       3
      1       4
      1       5
      2       6
```

А необходимо:

Отсортировать по `Par_id`, при этом значению `Par_id` соответствует какой-то `Chi_id` (возможно несколько), находим этот `Chi_id` в поле `Par_id` и сортируем. Далее процедура повторяется, пока не пробежимся по всем элементам.

Должна принять такой вид:

```
   Par_id  Chi_id
      0       1
      1       4
      1       5
      0       2
      2       6
      0       3
```

Всем Спасибо!

Comment: "при условии `Chi_id`" - при каком условии?

Comment: @kmv поправил условие.

Answer (score 3):

`SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY Chi_id,Par_id`  вот так!

Comment: опишите подробнее что вы хотите получить. У вас есть таблица выглядит оно так как на первом куске. а хотите как на втором?

Comment: Да, все верно. Немного поправил.

Comment: select * from   table_name  t1 
               start with t.id = ?
               connect by  prior  t.par_id = t.id;   на MySQL не знаю как пишется но на оракл писал вот так

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужно вывести дерево, упорядочив узлы сообразно их расположению в дереве, то это делается рекурсивным запросом:

```
;with tree
as (
    select
        Par_id, Chi_id,
        Sort_Key = cast(Chi_id as varbinary(400))
    from [TableName]
    where Par_id = 0
    union all
    select
        t.Par_id, t.Chi_id,
        cast(tree.Sort_Key + cast(t.Chi_id as varbinary(8)) as varbinary(400))
    from tree
        join [TableName] t on t.Par_id = tree.Chi_id
)
select Par_id, Chi_id
from tree
order by Sort_Key;
```

Answer (score 1):

Идея, предложенная в соседнем ответе верна, только ключ для сортировки должен составляться немного по-другому (в синтаксисе Transact-SQL):

```
with tree as (
    select Par_id, Chi_id,
        cast(Par_id as varchar(max)) + cast(Chi_id as varchar(max)) as k
    from TableName
    where Par_id = 0
    union all
    select t.Par_id, t.Chi_id,
        tree.k + cast(t.Par_id as varchar(max)) + cast(t.Chi_id as varchar(max))
    from tree
    join TableName t on t.Par_id = tree.Chi_id
)
select Par_id, Chi_id
from tree
order by k
```

Comment: @kvm Вам не трудно будет помочь с применением этой рекурсии для моего запроса. [Запрос](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=FAB1CBC465D83697!109&authkey=!AL1s0mLKOAi8-mA&ithint=file%2ctxt)

Comment: @romka-pm нужно данные из верхнего запроса вывести в таком виде? Можно выгрузить его во временную таблицу в том же with и затем использовать ее в рекурсивном запросе: http://pastebin.com/pH9gFSLr.

Comment: @kvm вид не важен. Ругается: "неправильный синтаксис возле конструкции with" (2 конструкции)

Comment: @romka.pm да, там ошибка. Слово with перед tree нужно убрать.

Comment: Такой ключ не совсем правильный. Если к исходным данным в старт-посте добавить две записи `(3, 7)` и `(3, 10)`, то при сортировке десятка пойдёт впереди семёрки, а не после.